# Ignore specific column on pg_dump/pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to ignore specific columns when dumping a PostgreSQL database using `pg_dump`? I have a table with columns X and Y. Is it possible to dump only column X with `pg_dump`?

Comment: Typically you use `\copy` with a `SELECT` for this sort of thing

Comment: Thats what pg_dump is using internally, was hoping for a secret select flag in the tool.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly; however, you could

```
CREATE TABLE b AS SELECT x FROM A;
```

and then pg_dump that.

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead. Since pg_dump already uses \copy internally I was hoping that I would be able to specify my own select.

Comment: See Craig Ringer's comment. I was being too literal.